error installing miniconda on a raspberry pi 4B
I was trying to install miniconda3 on my raspberry pi, and I keep getting the same error. It can download the bash file from https://docs.anaconda.com/miniconda/, but when I run it, I get
"./Miniconda3-latest-Linux-aarch64.sh: line 328: /home//miniconda3/_conda: No such file or directory"
I can go into miniconda3/ and see that _conda does in fact exist, so I'm not sure what's going on.
I've tried messing with permissions in the miniconda3/ folder, along with using miniforge instead of miniconda, but keep getting the same error

I had the same issue. If you run
file _conda

You probably don't have the required interpreter. I think it is ln-linux-aarch64.source-1 (or something, I was doing Miniforge but had the same error). You are probably running on a 32 bit OS. I just used Raspberry pi imager to get the 64 bit version.
See this:
https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=357800

You're right. I switched to the 64 bit version and it seems to work
